# Kendo for angular grid with grouping manipulate data within group

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, angular5, grouping

I am using a kendo for angular grid with grouping,  [this grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/grouping/), is it possible to take action only on records within a specific group?

For example, in the group header I have a button and every row has a check box, when the user clicks the button I need to get only the rows with in that group.

Or select all rows in one group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Grid Header Template](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupHeaderTemplateDirective/) we have access to the `group` property that in turns contains all data items for the respective group under its `items` property.

You can pass them to the custom button click handler and proceed accordingly:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
            <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate let-group let-field="field" let-value="value">
            <strong>{{field}}</strong>: {{value}} <button class="k-button" (click)="onClick(group)">CLICK</button>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/v5ILR0Hmv0R3NBmWmyVw?p=preview)

For example selecting all items from a group:

[REFERENCE ON SELECTION](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-during-data-operations)

[ENHANCED EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/UkFO5wOwvJUtb96D4Nv1?p=preview)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.